# Bokeh chart hover tool missing

Tags: python, charts, hover, visualization, bokeh

I'm trying to create donut chart in Bokeh, python.

I'm using Bokeh documentation example code :

```
from bokeh.charts import Donut, show, output_file
from bokeh.charts.utils import df_from_json
from bokeh.sampledata.olympics2014 import data

import pandas as pd

# utilize utility to make it easy to get json/dict data converted to a dataframe
df = df_from_json(data)

# filter by countries with at least one medal and sort by total medals
df = df[df['total'] > 8]
df = df.sort_values(by="total", ascending=False)
df = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['abbr'],
    value_vars=['bronze', 'silver', 'gold'],
    value_name='medal_count', var_name='medal')

# original example
d = Donut(df, label=['abbr', 'medal'], values='medal_count',
     text_font_size='8pt', hover_text='medal_count')

output_file("donut.html", title="donut.py example")

show(d)
```

But what I am getting is the chart without hover tool.

How can I put hover tool to this kind of chart?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you run the code, you would see a siderbar along with the plot - similar to one shown here:

[image]

Click on the second last icon - the one above the question mark. It reads "Hover" when you hover over it. Clicking it would enable/disable hover for you.

Comment: The problem is that that icon is not displayed. All of other icons are displayed but that hover tool icon is not.

Comment: Did you open and examine the html file formed?

Comment: Yes I tried both output_notebook() and also output_file(). In none of them is hover tool. The problem is that I can modify chart and add hover tool manually but the issue is that in that case hover tool does not show the tooltip properly. It displays ??? marks.

Comment: Could you paste the content of the html file somewhere?